# memory management error window 10 after chainging system configuration boot advance options

Tags: windows, windows-10

Actually this happend due to my mistake I guess. I try to change settings in systemconfiguration->boot -> Advance options and tried to changed of processes and max memory some values after that this error is appearing. And I dont know how to fix that. Even after reinstalling window its not getting solved.And memory_managment blue screen appearing/ what should I do ? I ran  Window diagnostic toll and no issue found there as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound  after reinstalling window 10 still memory management   blue screen appearing.